# Выполнить запрос SELECT с возвращением результатов

Tags: delphi, sqlite, sql

Как выполняются SELECT запросы в Delphi XE5 (SQLite)?

Comment: @Илья Дубчак, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно выполняются, связывайте компонент для запроса и **DataSourse** компонентом запроса отправляете запрос а в **DataSource** забираете результат выполнения запроса.